# Making different shapes of buttons using css3

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with making triangle shaped button using css and it is bit buggy and how can i fix it?

There is a fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Adrianalings/jy11o85s

```
.btn {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50%;
    height: 0px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid red;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution =)

```css
.btn {

width: 0px;
height: 0px;
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
border-style: solid;
border-width: 50px 0 50px 86.6px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #C40006;
background-color:transparent;

}
```

```html
<button class="btn"></button>
```